# How do I finish the proof or make this more rigorous? Outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

These are supposed to be a one-liner proof, but I can't make it rigorous for some reason.

> 1. Find $m^*(rE)$ in terms of $m^*(E)$ where $rE = \{rx: x \in E \}$.
> 2. Prove $m^*(E\cup F) \leq m^*(E) + m^*(F)$, for any set $E,F.$

For the first one, I simply thought that it was

> First we have, $m^*(E) = \inf \{\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} l(I_n) : E \subset \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_n \}$, so we get $m^*(rE) = \inf \{\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} l(rI_n) : rE \subset \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} rI_n \}$.
> But since $I_n$ is an interval, we have  $m^*(rE) = \inf \{\sum_{n =1}^{\infty} rl(I_n) : rE \subset \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} rI_n \}$. If $r > 0$, then it is $m^*(rE) = rm^*(E)$. but I don't know what happens if $ r < 0$. Is it even worth considering $r <0$ since measures are nonnegative?

For the second one, I just know that the key using the fact that the cover that covers $E \cup F$, covers $E$ and $F$, but I have a lot of difficulty writing out these ideas. There is a proof in the book that I am mimicking, but it is for countable sub additive. (comes after this problem)

> For $\epsilon > 0$, we have $$E \subset \bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{1,i}$$ and $$F \subset \bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{2,i}$$ and $\sum_{i \geq 1} m^*(I_{1,i}) \leq m^*(E) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\sum_{i \geq 1} m^*(I_{2,i}) \leq m^*(F) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$
>
> Then $E \cup F \subset \bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{1,i} \cup \bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{1,2}$, and so $$m^*(E \cup F) \leq m^*(\bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{1,i} \cup \bigcup_{i \geq 1} I_{1,2} )$$

Now I don't know how to proceed because the next inequality uses the result of this problem (I think), and it would be circular logic to continue. I honestly don't understand the formal/symbolic definition of the $\inf$ here so well either (the one that uses $\sum_{i \geq 1} m^*(I_{2,i}) \leq m^*(F) + \frac{\epsilon}{2}.$), I learned the "english" version where we state "any lower bound must be less than or equal to $\inf$" one. If someone could provide an description as to what is going on in ["for any $\epsilon >0$, $\exists s \in S$ such that $s < m + \epsilon$"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum#Formal_definition) it would be great. Wow just realize this is a long post.

Comment: For (1), your argument is fine. If $r<0$, then you have $m*(rE)=-r m*(E)$. You can combine the two cases into one statement using $|r|$.

Comment: @angryavian, If $r < 0$, it isn't true that $\inf (rS) = r\inf(S)$?

Comment: If $S=[1,2]$ and $r=-1$, then $\inf(rS)=-2$ while $r \inf(S)=-1$. However, I don't see what this has to do with (1).

Comment: @angryavian, i am saying $\inf(rS) \neq r\inf(S)$. So I don't understand the equality of your first comment.

Comment: Oh you mean to say $-rm^*(E)$.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), your argument is fine. If $r<0$, then you have $m^*(rE)=-r m^*(E)$. You can combine the two cases into one statement using $|r|$.

(2):

The infimum of a set is the greatest lower bound. Recall the example of interval $(0,1]$, which has infimum $0$, but does not contain $0$. This is precisely the reason why adding $\epsilon$ is necessary: although the set may not contain the infimum, it contains elements that are arbitrarily close to the infimum.

In the context of (2), there may not exist a cover of $E$ that has measure equal to the infimum, but there exists one that has measure less than the infimum plus $\epsilon/2$, for any $\epsilon>0$. By your work above,
$$m^*(E\cup F) \le m^*\left(\bigcup I_{1,i} \cup \bigcup I_{i,2}\right) \le m^*(E)+m^*(F) + \epsilon$$
for any $\epsilon>0$, so $m^*(E \cup F) \le m^*(E) + m^*(F)$.

Comment: How did you justify the second inequality? That's what I am concerned with.

Comment: @Hawk Oh I see. I used sub-additivity for the second inequality, but you are concerned because the proof of sub-additivity uses the result of this problem?

Comment: @Hawk Oh never mind, it's ok: since $\bigcup I_{1,i} \cup \bigcup I_{i,2}$ is a cover of itself, $$m^*\left(\bigcup I_{1,i} \cup \bigcup I_{i,2}\right) \le \sum l(I_{1,i}) + \sum l(I_{2,i}) \le m^*(E)+m^*(F)+\epsilon.$$

Comment: yeah that's what I meant. The proof here asks for "any set", does that mean "any set in $\Bbb R$" or literally any topological set?

Comment: @Hawk Since your definition of $m^*$ involves intervals, I assume they mean any set in $\mathbb{R}$. The reason why the fix in my previous comment is ok is because we are have the union of intervals, rather than an arbitrary set.